# erlang design of a card game

Tags: erlang, playing-cards

I would like to discuss with you a possible implementation for a card game in erlang.
The only full example I found online is [OpenPoker](https://github.com/wagerlabs/openpoker).

I would like to create one myself, so here is the implementation I have in mind:

1. A gen_server to represent a deck: when started creates a deck of cards (shuffled). And stores it in its state. provides an handle_call (draw_card)
2. A gen_server to represent the chat room. Stores in its state the registered name of a player process (e.g. player1, player2, luke etc etc). Exports handle_cast to join the chat (executed by default when somebody joins successfully the game) and one to broadcast a chat message to all users by calling an handle_cast on the gen_server representing a player.
3. a gen_fsm to represent a game instance. Has two states (wait_join, and turn). Exports join/1 to join the game, play_card/2 and send_msg/2. One parameter is the pid of the player process.
4. a gen_server to represent the player. Exports only start_link/1 where the parameter is the name to use to register the process (inside the init I call join method of gen_fsm). Has different handle_calls (e.g. get_hand, draw_card) and handle_casts (e.g. play_card, deliver_msg, and send_msg)
5. A gen_server to represent the main process. Exports (join_game/1 which calls player:start_link/1, send_msg/2 to call player's send_msg, play_card/3 to call player's play_card).

What do you think of this architecture?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is hard to answer. First, you need to have an idea of the problem you are trying to solve. Second, you need to understand the architecture. Third, you need to understand what the API to this thing will ultimately. Fourth, a proper answer will be long-winded. Fifth, A lot of the details are left out, so it is hard to put your finger on anything specific. Finally, it would be far better to try implement it first and then ask away if the architecture has problems.